# Get numerical value from parent with id like 'post-1' and use it in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out the following.

I have following jQuery code:

```
var as = "";
var bPlay = 0;
audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    as = audiojs.createAll();
    $(".audiojs .play-pause").click(function() {
        var e = $(this).parents(".audiojs").index(".audiojs");
        $.each(as, function(t, n) {
            if (t != e && as[t].playing) {
                as[t].pause()
            }
        })
        bPlay = !bPlay;
        if (bPlay == 1) {
            $(".bar").each(function(i) {
                fluctuate($(this));
            });
        } else {
            $(".bar").stop();
        }
    })
});
```

In a nutshell it preforms list of things when someone clicks particular .audiojs instance on a page. 1) checks if there is any other instance playing, if there is pauses it. And if it is playing applies fluctuate function to elements on a page that have `class="bar"`. This is the issue! I don't want to apply it to all .bar's on a page, but only to a specific group that is associated with particular .audiojs instance (the one that is being clicked and is playing).

I thought of the following solution. Each .audiojs instance is inside a div tag that has id like "post-1", "post-2" etc.. where numerical value is post id from database. I can add this numerical id to bar, so it would be like bar-1, bar-2 etc... However after this I'm having issues.

For javascript to work I need to retrieve numerical value from "post-[id]" associated with audiojs instance that is being clicked and than store it somehow, so I can use it like this afterwards

```
bPlay = !bPlay;
    if (bPlay == 1) {
        $(".bar-[value retrieved from post-...]").each(function(i) {
            fluctuate($(this));
        });
    } else {
        $(".bar-[value retrieved from post...]").stop();
    }
```

Could someone explain to me how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, the easiest way would be to stick it in a custom `data-*` attribute on the `<div id="post-X">` element, like so:

```
<div id="post-1" data-bar="bar-1">...</div>
```

Then, you said your `.audiojs` element is inside that `<div>`, so just go from `this` inside the event handler to that `<div>` element (using `.closest()`) and get the value of it:

```
var barId = $(this).closest('[id^="post-"]').attr('data-bar');
```

Then when you need to use it:

```
$("." + barId).each(function(i) {
    fluctuate($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of embedding the value in a class or ID, use a [data-* attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#custom-data-attribute):

```
<div class="audiojs" data-fluctuate-target="bar-1">
  <button type="button" class="play-pause">
    <!-- ... -->
  </button>
</div>

<div class="bar-1">
   <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

In your click event handler, use the following to fluctuate or stop the correct elements:

```
var fluctuateClass = $(this).closest('.audiojs').attr('data-fluctuate-target');
$('.' + fluctuateClass).each(function () {
  if (bPlay == 1) {
    fluctuate($(this));
  } else {
    $(this).stop();
  }
});
```